# Ejecutar acción de controlador en item seleccionados de grid - ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, gridview, grid

Estoy ingresando al desarrollo de ASP.net MVC 5 quisiera mostrar una grid con un listado de items de los cuales de acuerdo a los items que yo pueda seleccionar con check se ejecute un proceso que pueda definir desde mi controlador (no se si funcione como realizar un bucle con los items seleccionados).

Entonces mi consulta es que alternativas de desarrollo me pueden dar como orientación por ejemplo: que grid desarrollar con dicha funcionalidad? usar jQuery?  que herramientas existen para hacer lo que requiero?.

Les adjunta una imagen de un ejemplo que encontré, en resumido quisiera que de los item que yo pueda elegir y ejecutar una consultar SQL con los valores que pueda leer de las filas - columnas del item elegido:

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías utilizar un método ajax (Con jQuery, si lo prefieres) que invoque a tu controller pasandole un array con los id de los items seleccionados.

Comment: De acuerdo, y esto sería utilizando grid web? Tengo entendido que existe diversas grid para implementar en mvc 5

Comment: Si, hay muchos plugins/frameworks/componentes que te pueden ayudar a "pintar" un grid en el front (Elige el "flavor" que más te guste). Independiente de cual utilices, el mecanismo propuesto es que extraigas los ids (o identificadores) de los items que quieres enviar al back y lo envíes por ajax al controller como un array.

Comment: Me ayudaría inmensamente un ejemplo de como leer el id y poder enviarlo, estoy buscando algún post que contenga dicha información si por ahí conoces uno por favor compartirlo. Gracias!!

Comment: Bueno, dependerá de la implementación que tengas. De todas maneras, creo que te servirá ver este ejemplo: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706728/ASP-NET-MVC-Display-an-HTML-Table-with-Checkboxes